# Where would I ask a question about knowing the estimated performance of a game on a custom PC rig before having bought it?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

How would I know the average FPS of a certain game (i.e. **Fortnite**) on a custom gaming build without having bought it yet, something similar to how [BLD](https://www.nzxt.com/bldnow) displays the approx. FPS of a game that would run on a custom build they threw together for you?

Comment: I personally would consider any such tool to be *highly* suspect. The best way we have to estimate this is to use benchmarks, look at their rigs, and see how the performance changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to ask that would be Arqade, and we specifically don't allow quesitons that ask, "How well can system X run game Y?".  The best we do is redirect you to a canonical that asks that generally for system requirements.  Those types of questions are far too specific to a single user, and not for future readers.  I'm afraid there's nowhere to ask that type of question.